# Javascript pass parameters to onclick function in loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, closures

Any ideas to make this script work?

**I have two paragraphs:**

```
<p data-color="red">This textarea has a character limit of 50.</p>
<p data-color="blue">This one has a character limit of 40.</p>​
```

**And some JS:**

```
<script>
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p'),
    i = p.length;

while (i--) {
    color = p[i].getAttribute('data-color');
    p[i].onclick = function() {
        this.style.color = color;
    };
}​
</script>​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/4DGGz/)

I want the paragraphs to turn their specified colors when clicked. I need to pass each element's color into the onclick function.

Any Ideas?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Are you for/against jQuery? It would make doing this very easy

Comment: @JoshDavenport For this small snippet, I'd rather not use jQuery.

Comment: @JoshDavenport: It's very easy without jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p'),
    i = p.length;

while (i--) {
    p[i].onclick = function() {
        this.style.color = this.getAttribute('data-color');
    };
}​
</script>​
```

Comment: I said I want to pass the color into the function.

Comment: I don't want to have to calculate the value of the 'data-color' attribute on every click.

Comment: @Web_Designer. And he showed you a way without it. you should have mention it must be with a parameter!

Comment: you said,you need to, but you don't need, this is the proper soloution.

Comment: @gdoron I said it had to be passed into the function, sorry for the miscommunication. Any ideas?

Comment: This is just a test case, for my real life problem the `onclick` event is going to be fired Many Many times, and I don't want to have to calculate the 'data-color' attribute every iteration.

Answer (score -1):

OK, being downvoted bothers me, so I gave this another shot. Pure JS. Here's what I came up with. There's really no way, as was pointed out, to pass the color into the function as a variable. So instead, attaching a class to the paragraph tag and using that class as the color seemed the only way to avoid jQuery and offer a very simple solution. Since none of the paragraphs in the example code had classes to begin with, this seemed a viable solution. [Here's my jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/lazerblade01/LV9qX/)

Comment: For my specific problem I need to have it passed into the function. What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I'm guessing this code you presented is merely a simplification of your issue. I believe my edit contains a more specific solution to your question.

Comment: Your second example won't work. JavaScript doesn't have block scope, and the `theColor` parameter assigned to the handler will shadow the outer `theColor` anyway. What you'll actually get in the handler is the event object.

Comment: I had already tried that, here is your demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/4DGGz/1/

Comment: I'd rather not use jQuery for this small of a script.

Comment: Your updated code is still incorrect. You have the same issue as in the question. You've just shifted it from the `color` variable to the `i` variable